# Problem with parsing data at filestream and cvparser

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, constants

I'm having a problem reading this piece of code in a project that we are developing with colleagues. I'll be greateful if you can help me and tell me what that piece of code mean. I get that in that piece, I`m having the technologies.csv file and we need to parse it, and if there is an error we must throw an exception to this error. And at the end of the code there are some cards but i don't know what is the idea of this cards. And at the final we have to export the module with the data, and i think the data is from the const with the programing languages.If someone can explain it with details it would be more than perfect. Thanks in advance! :)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const path = require('path');

const constants = {
    testData: {
        csvColumns: [
            'ruby',
            'python',
            'vuejs',
            'angular',
            'react',
            'nodejs',
        ],
    },
};

const configFileLocation = (name) => {
    return
    {
      filename: path.join(__dirname, `${name}technologies.csv`)
    }
}

const getData = (name) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fileLocation = configFileLocation(name).filename;

        const csvParser = parse({
            delimiter: ',',
        });

        if (!fs.existsSync(fileLocation)) {
            reject(new Error(`File ${fileLocation} is missing.`));
        }

        const csvFileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileLocation);

        csvFileStream.on('ready', () => {
            csvFileStream.pipe(csvParser);
        });

        csvFileStream.on('error', (error) => {
            reject(
                new Error({
                    error,
                    message: 'csvParseCards#csvFileStream on error',
                })
            );
        });

        csvParser.on('error', (error) => {
            reject(
                new Error({
                    error,
                    message: 'csvParseCards#csvParser on error',
                })
            );
        });

        const cards = [];

        csvParser.on('readable', () => {
            let record = '';

            while ((record = csvParser.read())) {
                const card = {};

                const columns = constants.testData.csvColumns;

                if (record.length !== columns.length) {
                    console.warn('Column mismatch', record);
                }

                record.map((value, index) => {
                    card[columns[index]] = value;
                });

                cards.push(card);
            }
        });

        csvParser.on('end', () => {
            cards.shift();

            resolve(cards);
        });
    });

module.exports = getData;
```